# List<a> to List<b> converting when a and b have the same structur?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I use C# 3.5 DotNet Framework and Linq.

I have 2 Views which have the same result-schema, but in linq that are different objects of course.

How can I convert List a to List b?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the Cast<>() Method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new list of B's:

```
List<B> listOfB = listOfA.Select(a => new B {
                                                Foo = a.Foo,
                                                Bar = a.Bar,
                                                // etc...
                                            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

When they have the same structure, try take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

With AutoMapper you can do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
List<Destination> listDest = Mapper.Map<Source[], List<Destination>>(sources);
```